# How to weight additional data and keep initial results constant?

Tags: weights

I am analyzing some panel data with a varied number of households per week. To adjust for this variation I created a weighting that deflates the contribution of weeks with more than the average number of households per week and inflates weeks with fewer than the average number of households. I am happy with this but the problem arises when I receive more data. Increasing the number of households has an impact on the relative contribution of each household per week such that my estimates for weeks 1 to 3 using 4 weeks differ from estimates for weeks 1 to 3 using 3 weeks of data e.g.[image: HouseholdsPerWeekWeights]

This is a simplified version, in practice I am receive 52 weeks of data but the principle should be the same.

Is it possible to add in extra data whilst adjusting for variations in households numbers per week whilst keeping the results for weeks 1 to 3 consistent?

Comment: Perhaps you can rephrase (the title of) your question to make it relevant to a larger group of people. This may attract more readers and help you get help.

Comment: @bee guy Good idea, I struggled to think of a good title. What do you suggest?